# Notation: In "$\;z^c=\exp(w)\;$", what is $w$ exactly?

Tags: complex-analysis

What exactly is $w$ in the following?

> Let $z=1+i$ and $c=1-i$. If $z^c=\exp(w)$ what is the value of $Re(w)+Im(w)$ ?

I am not student of mathematics therefore I might have gaps between the basics. I have searched it in internet where it is said it's a complex variable. Question is: *which* complex variable?

Thanks

Comment: $W$ isn't given, basically they want you to find $W$ such that $e^W = Z^C$, so basically $W$ is the variable you're solving for. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Like with real numbers, you can write

$$z^c=e^w\to w=c\log z.$$

In the complex, the logarithm follows the rule (based on the polar form)

$$\log z=\log(re^{i(\theta+2k\pi)})=\log r+i(\theta+2k\pi).$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122977/discussion-on-answer-by-yves-daoust-notation-in-zc-expw-what-is-w).